# How to update only first row in SQlite DB which contains certain value?

Tags: android, sqlite

My little problem is:
I have **SQLite DB** in my app, which contains parameters of cards such as `cardInBaseID`(not id of a row), `cardName`, `cardValue` etc.
Now my DB has different cards which have cardInBaseID = 0 ;
I want to find first row in DB which contains `cardInBaseId = 0` , and update this value only for this row, not for all. How i can to this?

My method updateID works incorrect and update all rows which contains `cardInBaseID=0`:

```
public int updateID(String id ,String newID){
    SQLiteDatabase db =helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(helper.KEY_CARD_IN_BASE_ID,newID);
    String[] whereArgs ={id};
    int count=db.update(helper.TABLE_NAME,cv,helper.KEY_CARD_IN_BASE_ID+" =? ",whereArgs);
    return count;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the first row which has `cardInBaseId=0` through `cursor` and then update it

Comment: thanks for answer , how actually I need to use cursor?first I need to set cursor.moveToFirst , and when I update my cardInBaseId i need close my cursor , right?

Comment: i really dont understand , how i must set query for cursor and to implement cursir in my method  .Can u explain?

Comment: First create a method which returns you a cursor then move the cursor to the first index now get the first row and then update it simple